# OpenGL Sphere deforms when setting center coordinate to high values

Tags: c++, opengl

So I am drawing a sphere not using the "subdividing icosahedron" approach but using triangle strips and parameteric equation of the sphere.

Here is my code

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_SRIP);
for(float i = -PI/2; i < PI/2; i+= 0.01f)
{
    temp = i+0.01f;
    for(float j = 0; j < 2*PI; j+=0.01f)
    {
        temp -= 0.01f;
        glVertex3f( cx + rad * cos(j) * cos(temp), cy + rad * cos(temp) * sin(j), cz + rad * sin(temp));

        temp += 0.01f;
        glVertex3f( cx + rad * cos(j) * cos(temp), cy + rad * cos(temp) * sin(j), cz + rad * sin(temp));
    }
}
glEnd();
```

The approach is as followes. Imagine a Circle in the XY plane. This is drawn using the inner loop. Now imagine the XY plane moved above or below in the Z-axis and the radius changed cause it's a sphere. This is done using the outer loop. 
The first triangle coordinate is given for the Circle when XY plane is at its initial position. After `temp+=0.01f` the plane moved up by 0.01 and the second triangle vertex coordinate is given. This is how the strip is calculated.

The problem is if `cx = cy = cz = 0` or any low value like 2 or 3 the sphere seems fine. However if I put for e.g `cx = 15, cy = 15, cz = -6` the sphere gets deformed. Here is the picture.

[image: Sphere deformation]

If i use `GL_POINTS` this is what im getting

[image]

Comment: Is this your real code? I don't see anything related to that "displacement".

Comment: Have you checked, this is not a result due to perspective? I remember strange results, as matrix multiplication usually is not commutative.

Comment: @Ripi2 - yes it's the real code and that's what i don't understand.

Comment: @camelCase - How do i check if perspective is causing the issue? I'm initializing the projection matrix with `glFrustum(-50, 50, -50, 50, 1, 1000)`

Comment: To see a clear image I'd use a bigger increment, say 0.5 instead of 0.01. And also `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)` to see only edges.

Comment: @Ripi2 - i tried adding that but nothing changes. I also tried `GL_POINTS` the updated pic is shown in the post

Comment: Ok so i drew a `glutSolidTeapot` and used `glTranslatef(0, 10, 0)` and the result is the same. Some of the points get stuck on the center and the cube displaces. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry a very stupid mistake, I wasn't converting the values i put in `glFrustum` correctly hence a weird FOV was being generated. Solved the issue now. Thanks